# The premises (a ∧ b) ∨ c and c→ d imply which of the conclusion?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The choices for the question above are the following:

a) a ∨ c

b) a ∨ d

c) b ∨ d

d) b ∨ c

What I did was I first constructed the truth table for the (a ∧ b) ∨ c and c→ d to prove that they are logically equivalent. They aren't since the truth values are 10111000. Next, I set up each premise in the choices to see if they will match the truth values. All didn't. Am I doing it right? Or there is really no answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

The premise $(a\land b)\lor c$ is equivalent to $(a\lor c)\land(b\lor c)$, which implies both $a\lor c$ and $b\lor c$. And $a\lor c$ and $c\to d$ taken together imply $a\lor d$, while $b\lor c$ and $c\to d$ imply $b\lor d$, so all four of the choices are implied by the given premises.

Answer (score 0):

$a\land b$ being true means $a$ is true; and $c$ being true means $d$ is true.  We are told that either $(a\land b)$ or $c$ is true so that means $a$ or $d$ is true.

So b) is a valid conclusion.

The rest all are too be similar reason.  Either both of $a$ and $b$ are true OR both of $c$ and $d$ are true.  And the four conclusions are all covered in that.

========

If you want to use truth tables there are $16$ values, $a,b,c,d$ can be but:

$c\to d$ must be true so we can't have $c=1; d=0$. That rules out $4$ options.

$(a\land b)\lor c$ must be true so we can't have $c =0$ and $a$ or $b$ equal $0$. That rules out (bearing in mind $d$ can be $0$ or $1$) $6$ options

This leaves six options:

$A=1;B=1;C=1;D=1$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$\color{red}{A=1;B=1;C=1;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{c\to d=0}$.

$A=1;B=1;C=0;D=1$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$A=1;B=1;C=0;D=0$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$A=1;B=0;C=1;D=1$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$\color{red}{A=1;B=0;C=1;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{c\to d=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=1;B=0;C=0;D=1}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=1;B=0;C=0;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

$A=0;B=1;C=1;D=1$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=1;C=1;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{c\to d=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=1;C=0;D=1}$ this can be ignored because   $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=1;C=0;D=0}$ this can be ignored because   $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

$A=0;B=0;C=1;D=1$ then $a\lor c=1;a\lor d=1;b\lor d =1;b\lor c=1$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=0;C=1;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{c\to d=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=0;C=0;D=1}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

$\color{red}{A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0}$ this can be ignored because $\color{red}{(a\land b)\lor c=0}$.

=====

Or do do it a third way.

If $c$ is true then $d$ is true.  And so all $x \lor c$ and $x \lor d$ are true.  So all the conclusions are valid.

If $c$ is false then for $(a\land b) \lor c$ to be true we must have $a\land b$ to be true so we must have $a$ and $b$ both true.  So all $a\lor x$ and $b\lor x$ are true.  So all the conclusions are valid.

So either way all conclusions are valid.

or

If $a\land b$ is true then $a$ and $b$ are both true. so all $a\lor x$ and $b\lor x$ are valid conclusions.

If $a\land b$ is flase then for $(a\land b)\lor c$ to be true we must have $c$ be true.  So $c\to d$ means $d$ is true.  So all $x\lor c$ and $x \lor d$ are valid conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

> What I did was I first constructed the truth table for the (a ∧ b) ∨ c and c→ d to prove that they are logically equivalent. They aren't since the truth values are 10111000. Next, I set up each premise in the choices to see if they will match the truth values. All didn't. Am I doing it right?

No, you're not doing this right. Not even close, I'm sorry to say. This is a question about logical *implication*, not *equivalence*. For example, it is clear that a statement like $P \land Q$ implies statement $P$, even though they are not equivalent.

In fact, why did you even compare the truth-tables of the two premises with each other? That says nothing about whether they imply some *other* statement or not.

Likewise, comparing the truth-table of any of the options with an individual premise is of little use, since the questions is whether the two premises *together* imply some other statement.

So, if you are using a truth-table, you need to look at all the rows where both the premises are true, and then see if for any of provided statements, it is true that that statement is true in all those rows as well.

Please consult your book for some examples for how to do this.